# How can I route "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association" in ASP.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, handoff

What is the correct syntax to create a route in ASP.NET core?

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Handoff-iOS9",
                //url: ".well-known/apple-app-site-association",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=WellKnownAppleHandoff}" );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ApplePay",
               //url: ".well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=WellKnownApplePay}");
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

This does the trick

```
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Handoff-iOS9",  
                template: ".well-known/apple-app-site-association",
                defaults:  new { controller = "Home", action = "WellKnownAppleHandoff" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ApplePay-MacOS",
                template: ".well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "WellKnownApplePay" });

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```